# Derivative of $|x|^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to show that the derivative of $f = |x|^n$ does not exist at $x = 0$ for $ 0<n \le 1$. 
This is what I have so far.

For the right handed limit:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{|x|^n - 0}{x - 0} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{|x|^n}{x} = \lim |x|^{n-1}$

Since $0 < n \le 1$, we have that $n -1 < 0$. Thus if $x>0$ then the limit should equal $+\infty$. However, I'm not sure how to find the left handed limit. This is what I have tried:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{(-x)^n}{x} = \lim (-1)^n (x)^{n-1}$.

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Try with $(-1)^nx^{n-1}=(-1)(-x)^{n-1}=(-1)|x|^n$

Comment: Anyway better not to trust the elementary properties of powers for non integer exponents and negative bases, your last line would be better defined using ${(-x)^n \over x} = -{(-x)^n \over (- x)}=-(-x)^{n-1}$, as $(-x)$ is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-hand limit is enough. Derivatives cannot be infinite; if the right derivative "is infinite", then the function is not differentiable.

If you want to do the left side, remember the absolute value signs, and make a substitution $x\mapsto -y$:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{|x|^n-0}{x-0}=-\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{|y|^n}{y}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{(-x)^n}{x} = -\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{(-x)^n}{-x}$$ so what if we let $t = -x$?